# Find the general solution to 2y''+xy'+y = 0 in the form of a power series about the ordinary point x=0.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

**Question:**

> Find the general solution to $2y''+xy'+y = 0$ in the form of a power series about the ordinary point $x=0$.

---

**My Working:**

Firstly $\space y = \sum\limits_{0}^{\infty} (A_n.(x-1)^n)$

And then I took the first and second derivative and plugged them into the main equation above.

> Now I am stuck on the part where I find the values of the Coefficients. How to proceed?

Comment: Please share the results of plugging in the first and second derivatives.  It's possible you are stuck because of a mistake that crept in already, and if not, it will expedite a Reader's response to pick up the thread of your existing calculation.

Comment: About $x=1$ or $x=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to find a recurrence relation for the coefficients using the power series inserted into the original ODE.